# Is there a specific notation for a final static class in UML?

Tags: uml, data-modeling

How do you declare a class as final static in UML?
We use the italic convention for Abstract Classes but I can't seem to find any information for final static classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"final"?** keyword

So I assume that you talk about Java Programming Language.

**Java final?**

And I assume that you talk about final class in Java

**Java final static class**?

You can not define static class in Java. Only nested classes can be static.
Here is a sample Java code with nested classes.

```
public final class MyFinalClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        StaticNestedClassA.WhoIamI();
        StaticNestedClassB.WhoIamI();
    }


    public  static class StaticNestedClassA
    {
        public static void WhoIamI()
        {
            System.out.println("I am static class A");
        }

    }
    public final static class FinalStaticNestedClassB
    {

        public static void WhoIamI()
        {
            System.out.println("I am final static class B");
        }
    }
}
```

And a posible UML class diagram is:[ "leaf" tag-sterotype for final class ]

[image]

**And be carefull "final" has different meaning in Java when used as a variable**.
Another Java sample code

```
public class MySingletonClass 
{
    private MySingletonClass()
    {

    }

    private final static MySingletonClass me = new MySingletonClass();

}
```

And a possible  UML representation is : ["readonly" once assigned then can not be changed]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that it's PHP. I'm using a PHP Final Static class to define all the namespace kernel events in Symfony2. We're now using <<final static>> to denote the class. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, UML is pretty much unaware of language-specific features.

Comment: But it has many features that appear across different languages - being able to mark a class as non-specializable is not Java-specific and is an example of that.

Answer (score 1):

From the UML superstructure specification v2.4.1, section 7.3.8, Classifier:

> isFinalSpecialization: Boolean if true, the Classifier cannot be
>   specialized by generalization.(...)  Default is false.

That is equivalent to a final modifier in a Java class.

Re: static classes - are you talking about inner static classes? UML supports setting features (operations and attributes) as static, but not inner classes.

Comment: I see you are talking about PHP. What purpose a static class has in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

final should be all in CAPS, static should be underlined